# Performance difference between single vs splitting into multiple files in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am using spark to load a very large text file with gzip compression into hive. I would like to know which would give better performance( or if it does not matter)?

1. Unzipping the gzip file into a single uncompressed file and using it in spark
2. Unzipping the gzip file and then splitting the uncompressed file into multiple files and using the folder containing the multiple files in spark

Thanks

Comment: When loading a very large text file with gzip compression into Spark for use in Hive, the performance difference between using a single uncompressed file and using multiple files can depend on various factors. Unzipping the gzip file into a single uncompressed file and using it in Spark may be suitable if the file size is manageable and the processing can be efficiently parallelized. On the other hand, unzipping the gzip file and then splitting the uncompressed file into multiple files can be beneficial for parallel processing and optimizing the distribution of data across partitions.